# Google Voice line break

Tags: javascript, node.js, sms, mms, google-voice

I am using google voice paired with the voice.js node.js module. I am trying to send a sms message with a line break but nothing seems to work. I have tried \n, \r, \r\n, %0a, %0A. Is there some way to do this that I'm not aware of? If you have any thoughts or solutions I'd like to hear them.

thanks!

Comment: How are you encoding the message? Perhaps posting your code would help.

Comment: i believe the module does encode the requests